# Invalid main class for MANIFEST.MF Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea

I'm learning servlets and jsps, and now I'm trying to generate my WAR file. As far as I'm aware, I need to create a MANIFEST.MF file in order to accomplish it. I'm able to generate the WAR file using Intellij IDEA but once I copy it to /webapps (subdirectory of tomcat home) and run Tomcat, I'm unable to run the application. I get a warning in the MANIFEST.MF saying `Invalid main class` where I declare `Main-Class` attribute. I do this: `Main-Class: demo.Hello`

```
// Hello.java
package demo;
@WebServlet(name = "Hello")
public class Hello extends HttpServlet {
    public Hello() { super(); }
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    }
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
         PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
         out.println("Hello");
    }
}


// MANIFEST.MF - class path is set to where Hello.java is stored
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: /home/.../src
Main-Class: demo.Hello
```

Do you have any ideas how to solve this?

Note: Intellij IDEA runs the web application directly on localhost:8080, even if I set another Application Context. I don't know why.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For web applications there is no need to add the Main-Class entry in Manifest file. This entry is to make your jar executable.

Comment: @SethMcClaine I think it does provide an answer to the question, just like the answer by EJP which came an hour later. A WAR file just doesn't need a main class or method.

Comment: Thanks, you're right. Now I'm facing a problem deploying the war file. In tomcat log I get this: 
`24-Dec-2015 11:50:00.217 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.` When I go `localhost:8080/Deployment` I get 404 error.

Answer (score 2):

If you use maven to build your project the maven-war-plugin or maven-jar-plugin can generate the manifest for you.

As for your application always executing at http://localhost:8080 I think that you need to specify the path for the servlet with @WebServlet("/somePath").You have provided the name attribute and not the path.

If that is not what you meant then could you tell us how you are deploying your project? Which application server are you using? Is it an ear inside a war file or just a war file? If it is just a war file then you should be able to set the contextPath for the application in web.xml

Answer (score 2):

WAR files don't need a `Main-class` attribute, and `demo.Hello` is not a main class (no `public static void main(String[] args)` method).

Just remove the `Main-class` attribute.